# Magneto2 - How can I remove product image fullscreen and zoom in mobile product page

Tags: magento2, fotorama-slider

I want to enable product zoom and fullscreen light box on desktop but disable them on mobile. I am working on 2.1.6 in theme `etc/view.xml`.
I can remove/enable product images fullscreen light box on desktop.

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
```

remove/enable product image zoom in desktop

```
<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

I tried to apply this in mobile breaks points like below, but it does not work for both fullscreen and zoom.

```
<var name="breakpoints">
    <var name="mobile">
        <var name="conditions">
            <var name="max-width">767px</var>
        </var>
        <var name="options">
            <var name="options">
                <var name="nav">dots</var>
                <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
                <var name="magnifier">
                    <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
</var>
```

Thanks for any help and comments

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same issue and then found the below working solution. Hope will help someone.

```
   <var name="breakpoints">
        <var name="mobile">
            <var name="conditions">
                <var name="max-width">767px</var>
            </var>
            <var name="options">
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="nav">thumbs</var>
                    <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!--If want full screen then make it true. Zoom function will automatically disabled-->
                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </var>
```

Comment: This is the working answer, tested in 2.2.7

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tests, I found that there aren't necessarily double "options".
To avoid fullscreen on mobile devices, must set false also for normal devices.

```
<var name="breakpoints">
    <var name="mobile">
        <var name="conditions">
            <var name="max-width">767px</var>
        </var>
        <var name="options">
            <!--<var name="options">-->
            <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
                <var name="nav">dots</var>
            </var>
            <!--</var>-->
        </var>
    </var>
</var>
```